# File upload with Jersey - FormDataContentDisposition is null

Tags: javascript, java, rest, jersey

I am quite aware that there are a lot of questions same as this one, but none of them are helping me since my HTML file name is the same as the one in JavaScript and Java. Here is JavaScript code:

```
        var fd = new FormData();
        fd.append('firstName', $scope.user.firstName);
        fd.append('lastName', $scope.user.lastName);
        fd.append('phoneNumber', $scope.user.phoneNumber);
        fd.append('email', $scope.user.email);
        fd.append('username', $scope.user.username);
        fd.append('password', $scope.user.password);
        fd.append('file', $scope.user.profilePicture);
        fd.append('file', $scope.user.profilePicture.name);
        console.log("Image:" + $scope.user.profilePicture);
        console.log("Image name:" + $scope.user.profilePicture.name);
```

When i `console.log("Image name:" + $scope.user.profilePicture.name);` everything seems fine, but the moment i send request i get `null`. Here is Java code:

```
    @Path("/register")
    @POST
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    public Response registerUser(
            @FormDataParam("firstName") String firstName,
            @FormDataParam("lastName") String lastName,
            @FormDataParam("phoneNumber") String phoneNumber,
            @FormDataParam("email") String email,
            @FormDataParam("username") String username,
            @FormDataParam("password") String password,
            @FormDataParam("file") InputStream uploadedInputStream,
            @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDescription,
            @Context ServletContext servletContext) throws JsonGenerationException, JsonMappingException, IOException {


        String uploadedFileLocation = servletContext.getRealPath("/resources/images")+"/"+fileDescription.getFileName();

        writeToFile(uploadedInputStream, uploadedFileLocation);

        String imgPath = "http://localhost:8080/WebProjekat/resources/images/" + fileDescription.getFileName();
        User user = new User(username, password,firstName,lastName,phoneNumber,email,imgPath);

        if(userService.addUser(user)) {
            return Response.status(Status.CREATED)
                    .entity(user)
                    .build();
        }else 
            return Response.status(Status.NOT_ACCEPTABLE)
                    .entity(user)
                    .build();

    }
```

somehow FormDataContentDisposition fileDescription is always null. Here is HTML code:

```
<div class="form-group">

    <img style="max-height: 250px; max-width: 200px;" src="app/image_resources/guest.png" id="profileImg"></img>

    <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" style="width: 100%;height: 30px; display: flex;align-items: center;justify-content: center;" value="Load Image" onclick="$('#loadProfileImg').click();" />

    <input type="file" accept="image/*" class="form-control" id="loadProfileImg" ng-required="true" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().readURL(this);" style="display:none;" name="file" />
```

As you can see i have named

```
<input type='file'>
```

the same as i did the key back in JavaScript . I also included this inside my web.xml:

```
<init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
            <param-value>org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPartFeature</param-value>
</init-param>
```

ANY kind of help will be appreciated. Thank you guys in advance!

**UPDATE**: I have fixed the null problem, i accidently wrote:

```
fd.append('file', $scope.user.profilePicture);
        fd.append('file', $scope.user.profilePicture.name);
```

instead of:

```
fd.append('file', $scope.user.profilePicture, $scope.user.profilePicture.name);
```

But sadly i have another issue. Now my img path is correct but i am getting 404 NOT FOUND even though i see image name inside the folder it was meant to upload, but i cannot see the image itself. I am using this code on 2 more different objects and it works fine.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Read the url append the form data .

```
<input type="file" class="form-control" id="file" ng-model="file"
       onchange="angular.element(this).scope().getTheFiles(this)" />
```

### Controller

```
var formdata = new FormData();
$scope.getTheFiles = function(element) {
    $scope.$apply(function($scope) {
        $scope.files = element.files;
        for (var i = 0; i < element.files.length; i++) {
            formdata.append('files', element.files[i]);
        }
    });
};
```

### Next send the URL

Java side get value like `@FormDataParam("files") List<FormDataBodyPart>` files.